# Calling a JavaScript method before rendering

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I have one-page app where header, footer and top navigation are static and the "pages" are opened with Ajax.

Example:

Element from the main navigation:

```
<a href="javascript:;" data-open-dynamic="/project/controllerName/actionName/">Something</a>
```

JavaScript:

```
$('body').on('click', '[data-open-dynamic]', function () {
    var url = $(this).data('openDynamic');
    openDynamic(url);
})

function openDynamic(url)
{
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        async: true,
        success: function (data) {
            //some other logic
            $('.content').html(data).fadeIn();
        }
    })
}
```

The problem is that I need to open these pages from direct URLs also. Now if I try to open `domain.com/controllerName/actionName` the design is broken as the layout is set to `ajax` in the controller:

```
public function initialize()
{
    parent::initialize();
    $this->layout = 'ajax';
}
```

I tried to do something with `beforeFilter()`, `beforeRender()`, `shutdown()` but it seems the JavaScript file containing the method `openDynamic()` is not loaded yet and I can't call it.

```
public function beforeRender(\Cake\Event\Event $event)
{
    parent::beforeRender($event);

    $url = $event->subject->request->here; // the URL is correct
    echo 'openDynamic("' . $url . '");';

    $this->response->stop();
}
```

Also I'm not sure if the header, footer and navigation will be loaded properly in this way. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

How about only setting the layout to be `ajax` if the page is requested via AJAX? You can test this using `$this->request->is('ajax')`:-

```
public function beforeRender(\Cake\Event\Event $event)
{
    parent::beforeRender($event);
    if ($this->request->is('ajax')) {
        $this->layout = 'ajax';
    }
}
```

This would be cleaner than mixing JavaScript with PHP in your code.

Comment: Or use [**the request handler component**](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/controllers/components/request-handling.html) that does this stuff automatically.